# Where to indicate the key property when mapping an array in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in one of our projects and there's this page where in I need to map over an array which will render a list of `<InnerComponent />` in a grid of 3 columns. However, I needed to include the bootstrap column  for each array child that the map function returns. And since `<div>` is the direct child, then I have to put they 'key' property into it like so:

```
somearray.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div
            className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12"
            key={item.id}
        >
            <InnerComponent />
        </div>
    );
})
```

Is this valid? Or should the key be always added as a component prop?

Comment: sounds like you don't really know what key is for. read this page from the official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: What you are doing is correct you just make sure key.id is unique otherwise you will get only first element